# How to get a child entity through parent field

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application with two entities. I am trying to get one entity through its foreing key but am getting the error, that it is not present eventhough it is present their. Maybe someone can give me a pointer:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "meeting_settings")
@Setter
@Getter
public class MeetingsSetting implements Serializable {
    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "meetingName", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<MeetingTime> meetingTime = new HashSet<>();
}
```

MeetingTimeEntity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "meeting_times")
@Getter
@Setter
public class MeetingTime implements Serializable {

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "meeting_name" ,insertable = false, updatable = false, referencedColumnName = "meeting_name")
    private MeetingsSetting meetingName;
}
```

This is my repository MeetingTime:

```
@Repository
public interface MeetingTimeRepository extends JpaRepository<MeetingTime, Long> {

    public List<MeetingTime> findMeetingTimeByMeetingName(MeetingTime meeting_name);       
}
```

And finally my service:

```
@Service
public class MeetingTimeService {

    @Autowired
    MeetingTimeRepository meetingTimeRepository;

            public List<MeetingTime> findMeetingTimeByName(MeetingTime meeting_name){
                return meetingTimeRepository.findMeetingTimeByMeetingName(meeting_name);
            }
}
```

And the controller which is calling it:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/meetingTime")
public class MeetingTimeController {

    @Autowired
    MeetingTimeService meetingTimeService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/{meeting_name}" )
    public List<MeetingTime> getTimesByName(@RequestParam MeetingTime meeting_name){
     return  meetingTimeService.findMeetingTimeByName(meeting_name);
    }
}
```

THe error I am getting is the following:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required request parameter 'meeting_name' for method parameter type MeetingTime is not present]
```

This happens when I give MeetingSetting as a Pathvariable, I tried giving it string because the foreign key meeting_name is a varchar but then I am getting the error that the expected type was MeetingSetting. If I use forexample date to find my entities they are found easily

Answer (score 0):

I think ,  `@RequestParam` is invalid...  it must change to `@PathParam`

Comment: pathparam wants to have an paramet?

Answer (score 0):

First, why do you use `MeetingTime` for parameter to `findMeetingTimeByMeetingName`? From what I see, you use `MeetingsSetting` as the join column in the entity, so you should use `MeetingsSetting` instead of `MeetingTime`.

Also, you can try to do the query using the foreign key meeting_name value

Try to use this one on the `MeetingTimeRepository`

```
public List<MeetingTime> findAllByMeetingNameId(String meetingNameId);
```

I'm assuming you have id field on the MeetingsSetting with String data type.

Lastly, I don't think you can use Object as path variable as it can have multiple values.

Comment: What do you mean? I am not mapping through Id but through meetingName. I also have a string meeting_name parameter on meetingTime which is connected to the foreignkey but still it does not work

Comment: Does `MeetingsSetting` contain meeting_name field?  From your problems what I understand is that you want to search all meeting time with specific meeting name foreign key, right? Which in spring boot you can use [query property expressions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions) for that.

Comment: Hi, I posted my solution thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I kinda fixed it by changing repo method to this:

```
List<MeetingTime> findMeetingTimeByMeetingName_MeetingName(String meetingName);
```

And using @RequestParam like this: `@RequestParam("meetingName")`
in the controller